# External Inputs to an Arduino

Tags: input, serial-port, arduino, external, microcontroller

I'm doing a school project and I have an Arduino Leonardo and I am trying to get an intergrated circuit to communicate with it using serial.

Is this even possible?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to electronics.stackexchange.com (but that is not listed in the "another site..." option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look into the [Software Serial library](http://arduino.cc/de/Reference/SoftwareSerial). However if you look into the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/7766s.pdf) you will find, that the ATmega16/32U4 controllers have a hardware UART. So the real reason for "no serial interface" is that the Arduino designers chose to not support it. With [this tutorial](http://www.appelsiini.net/2011/simple-usart-with-avr-libc) and the datasheet it should not be to hard to get real hardware serial support.

So yes, it is definitely possible.